# Software usage analytics in C#

Tags: c#, service, monitoring, usage-statistics

I have a project i am working on currently and would like to implement some sort of software tracking in the code. ideally, stuff like how often its launched. how long it runs for, feature tracking, etc. I already use Exceptioneer for unhandled exceptions, but would like something similar for usage tracking.

this data should all be anonymous and ideally run as a service by someone else. and i would like to give the users the option to turn it off, if they so wish to... So, is this something i should implement myself, or are there third parties out there that do this sort of things? i know it might be a sticky area, but i have seen stats about iPhone app usage. they do it, so why cant we? (if the user agrees, of course)

[Update] Based on the comments, i should have been more clear. this is a Winforms .NET 4. application, though i am thinking of updating it later with WCF. i would only be tracking my own application, though i would also want to know minor information about environment (Windows OS Version, SP, maybe proc and ram...)

Comment: Google analytics could work for feature and usage tracking

Comment: What type of app?  Winforms, asp.net, silverlight, etc?

Comment: Are you talking about monitoring the usage of arbitrary programs on a desktop PC?

Comment: That can be classified as Runtime Intelligence. You can use analytics tools such as *http://www.trackerbird.com*  (Disclaimer: I am affiliated with the company)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems after a bit more digging, i have found a couple of sites that offer this. any extras, please leave a comment:

[Premeptive Runtime Intelligence: Free community version](http://preemptive.com/products/runtime-intelligence/overview)
[DeskMetrics: free for one app, $49 for more...](http://deskmetrics.com/)

any other suggestions?

Comment: their site actually says free for up to 500! nice find!

Comment: Since the previous msg was deleted, TiernanO's comment refers to http://www.trackerbird.com Software Analytics

Comment: After testing a couple of ready solutions for Windows and MacOS X, I made my own library to track my shareware titles via google analytics. 
I am giving the library to any other interested shareware developers. 
https://www.starmessagesoftware.com/blog/runtime-analytics-windows-macosx-with-google-analytics

Answer (score 4):

+1 to deskmetrics. There is an library for .net apps. Check out: https://github.com/deskmetrics/NET

I've heard they're investing pretty hard on others platforms (like Adobe Air and Mac/Cocoa). It is worthy to keep eyes on them.

Answer (score 2):

Well, i've seeing watching fantastic user feedback on DeskMetrics, a company that calls itself 'Google Analytics for Desktop Software'. They've been profiled recently on [TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2010/10/29/deskmetrics-wants-to-be-a-google-analytics-for-desktop-software/), so i'd recommend to keep an eye at their product.

Answer (score 1):

There are several third party products that do this kind of software analytics. One of the better ones is called Aternity.

See: http://www.aternity.com/

Comment: thanks for the link, but their site seems too complicated to get around... cant find a price, cant find a download links...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use google analytics to track your app usage.
GaDotNet is a free library to integrate Google analytics tracking in your application:

more info here : http://www.diaryofaninja.com/projects/details/ga-dot-net