# Defining a webservice for usage analytics (dekstop application)

Tags: mysql, database, analytics, desktop-application, database-normalization

**Current situation**
I have a desktop application (C++ Win32), and I wish to track users' usage analytics anonymously (actions, clicks, usage time, etc.)
The tracking is done via designated web services for specific actions (install, uninstall, click) and everything is written by my team and stored on our DB.

**The need**
Now we're adding more usage types and events with a variety of data, so we need define the services.
Instead of having tons of different web services for each action, I want to have a **single** generic service for all usage types, that is capable of receiving different data types.
For example:

- "button_A_click" event, has data with 1 field: {window_name (string)}
- "show_notification" event, has data with 3 fields: {source_id (int), user_action (int), index (int)}

**Question**
I'm looking for an elegant & convenient way to store this sort of diverse data, so later I could query it easily.
The alternatives I can think of:

- Storing the different data for each usage type as one field of JSON/XML object, but it would be extremely hard to pull data and write queries for those fields
- Having extra N data fields for each record, but it seems very wasteful.

Any ideas for this sort of model? Maybe something like google analytics? please Advise...

**Technical:** The DB is MySQL running under phpMyAdmin.

**Disclaimer:**
There is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799040/software-usage-analytics-in-c-sharp), which brought to my attention services like [DeskMetrics](http://deskmetrics.com/) and [Tracker bird](http://www.trackerbird.com/), or try to embed google analytics to C++ native application, but I'd rather the service to by my own, and better understand how to design this sort of model.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) problem.

I am also going to assume that you also have a table named `events` where all events will be stored.

Additionally, I am going to assume you have to the following data attributes (for simplicity's sake): `window_name, source_id, user_action, index`

To achieve normalization, we will need the following tables:

```
events
data_attributes
attribute_types
```

This is how each of the tables should be structured:

```
mysql> describe events;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| event_type | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe data_attributes;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| event_id        | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| attribute_type  | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| attribute_name  | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| attribute_value | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe attribute_types;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| type  | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The idea is that you will have to populate `attribute_types` with all possible types you can have. Then, for each new event, you will add an entry in the `events` table and corresponding entries in the `data_attributes` table to map that event to one or more attribute types with the appropriate values.

Example:

```
"button_A_click" event, has data with 1 field: {window_name "Dummy Window Name"}
"show_notification" event, has data with 3 fields: {source_id: 99, user_action: 44, index: 78}
```

would be represented as:

```
mysql> select * from attribute_types;
+----+-------------+
| id | type        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | window_name |
|  2 | source_id   |
|  3 | user_action |
|  4 | index       |
+----+-------------+

mysql> select * from events;
+----+-------------------+
| id | event_type        |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | button_A_click    |
|  2 | show_notification |
+----+-------------------+

mysql> select * from data_attributes;
+----+----------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| id | event_id | attribute_type | attribute_name    | attribute_value |
+----+----------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|  1 |        1 |              1 | Dummy Window Name |            NULL |
|  2 |        2 |              2 | NULL              |              99 |
|  3 |        2 |              3 | NULL              |              44 |
|  4 |        2 |              4 | NULL              |              78 |
+----+----------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

To write a query for this data, you can use the [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function in MySQL to get the value for you without having to check which of the columns is `NULL`.

Here's a quick example I hacked up:

```
SELECT  events.event_type as `event_type`, 
        attribute_types.type as `attribute_type`, 
        COALESCE(data_attributes.attribute_name, data_attributes.attribute_value) as `value`
FROM    data_attributes,
        events,
        attribute_types
WHERE   data_attributes.event_id = events.id
AND     data_attributes.attribute_type = attribute_types.id
```

Which yields the following output:

```
+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+
| event_type        | attribute_type | value             |
+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+
| button_A_click    | window_name    | Dummy Window Name |
| show_notification | source_id      | 99                |
| show_notification | user_action    | 44                |
| show_notification | index          | 78                |
+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Bugger! I read C#, but I see you are using C++. Sorry about that. I leave the answer as-is as its principle could still be useful. Please regard the examples as pseudo-code.

You can define a custom class/structure that you use with an array. Then serialize this data and send to the WebService. For example:

```
[Serializable()]
public class ActionDefinition {
    public string ID;
    public ActionType Action; // define an Enum with possible actions
    public List[] Fields;  //Or a list of 'some class' if you need more complex fields
}

List AnalyticsCollection = new List(Of, Actiondefinition);

// ...
SendToWS(Serialize(AnalyticsCollection));
```

Now you can dynamically add as many events as you want with the needed flexibility.

on server side you can simply parse the data:

```
List[of, ActionDefinition] AnalyticsCollection = Deserialize(GetWS());

foreach (ActionDefinition ad in AnalyticsCollection) {
    switch (ad.Action) {
        //.. check for each action type
    }
}
```

I would suggest adding security mechanisms such as checksum. I imagine the de/serializer would be pretty custom in C++ so perhaps as simple Base64 encoding can do the trick, and it can be transported as ascii text.

Comment: thanks, but serialization is not the problem (even in C++). The problem is querying and finding data in the DB with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a table for each event in wich you declare what param means what. Then you have a main table in wich you only input the events name and param1 etc. An admin tool would be very easy, you go through all events, and describe them using the table where each event is declared. E.g. for your event button_A_click you insert into the description table:

```
Name                   Param1
button_A_Click    WindowTitle
```

So you can group your events or select only one event ..

This is how I would solve it.

Comment: 1 parameter is not enough for all event types (some events requires several parameters). I can add 5 (or 10) paramters, but it's the same as the 2 alternative i said earlier, but it seems too wasteful.